# Ball Keeps Glitching On The Paddle Pong How To Fix? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

when ever my ball collides with my paddles the ball keeps glitching with the paddles [Video](https://gyazo.com/170ba8234d1a68542aac3b49b34b73eb)

```
    if ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman.rect) or ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman2.rect):
        ball1.velx *= -1
        ball1.velx += 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: Perhaps your collision detection code is being triggered more than once for each collision? Showing more of what you've tried will make it easier to diagnose your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why Are you saying += 1?

Does it have some specific purpose?

I've made more than 10 tiny and 2 big games with pygame but don't get this!

maybe try

```
if ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman.rect):
        ball1.velx *= -1
        ball1.velx += 1
        ball1.x = playerman.x + (playerman.rect.width / 2) + 5
elif ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman2.rect)
    ball1.velx *= -1
        ball1.velx -= 1
        ball1.x = playerman.x - (playerman2.rect.width / 2) - 5
```

if that doesn't work do this

```
if ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman.rect):
        ball1.velx *= -1
        ball1.velx -= 1
        ball1.x = playerman.x + (playerman.rect.width / 2) + 5
elif ball1.rect.colliderect(playerman2.rect)
    ball1.velx *= -1
        ball1.velx += 1
        ball1.x = playerman.x + (playerman2.rect.width / 2) + 5
```

Comment: And if not that maybe explain your question